# Where can I find documentation on assembler?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, assembly, ld, gnu-assembler

I wrote a very short program that parses a "program" using python and converts it to assembler, allowing me to compile my little proramming language to an executable.

You can read my blog for more information here  http://spiceycurry.blogspot.com/2010/05/simple-compilable-programming-language.html

my question is... Where can I find more kernel commands so that I can further expand on my script in the above blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather recomment using [LLVM](http://llvm.org/):

- It allows you not to bother with low-level details like register allocations (you provide only SSA form)
- It does optimizations for you. It can be faster then the hand-written and well-optimized compiler as the LLVM pipeline in GHC is showing (at the beginning - before much optimalization it had equal or better performance than mature native code generator).
- It is cross-platform - you don't tight yourself to for example x86

I'n not quite sure what you mean by 'kernel' commands. If you mean opcodes:

- There are [Intel manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/)
- There is Wikipedia page containing all of the documented memnonics (however not the opcodes and not always description)
- There is [NASM manual](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html)

However the ARM or PowerPC have totally different opcodes.

If you mean the operating systen syscalls (system calls) then:

- You can just use C library. It is in every operating system and is cross platform.
- You can use directly syscalls. However they are harder to use, may be slower (libc may use additional buffering) and are not cross platform ([Linux syscalls on x86](http://bluemaster.iu.hio.no/edu/dark/lin-asm/syscalls.html) - may be not up-to-date).